# Python C-API int128 support

Tags: python, cpython, python-c-api, int128

In python one can handle very large integers (for instance `uuid.uuid4().int.bit_length()` gives 128), but the largest `int` datastructure the [C-API documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html) offers is `long long`, and it is a [64-bit `int`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Basic_types).

I would love to be able to get a C `int128` from a `PyLong`, but it seems there is no tooling for this. [PyLong_AsLongLong](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_AsLongLong) for instance cannot handle python integers bigger than `2**64`.

- Is there some documentation I missed, and it is actually possible?
- Is there currently not possible, but some workaround exist? (I would love to use the tooling available in the python C-API for `long long` with int128, for instance a `PyLong_AsInt128AndOverflow` function).
- Is it a planed feature in a forthcoming python release?

Comment: I think you're confusing python's arbitrary length integers with c's integer types.  Assuming that `uuid.uuid4().int.bit_length() == 128` (which is not always true), you could do something like `print((uuid.uuid4().int * 4).bit_length())` and you should get a number <= 130.  That shouldn't suggest that Python is using "int130" -- only that Python supports arbitrary length integers.

Comment: I edited my post so it is more accurate. The only thing I would like to do is to get a C `int128` from a python `PyLong`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of different ways you can access the level of precision you want.

Systems with 64-bit `long`s often have 128-bit `long long`s. Notice that the article you link says "**at least** 64 bits". It's worth checking `sizeof(long long)` in case there's nothing further to do.

Assuming that is not what you are working with, you'll have to look closer at the raw [`PyLongObject`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/47290e7642dd41d94437dd0e2c0f6bfceb0281b5/Include/longobject.h#L10), which is actually a `typedef` of the private [`_longobject`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/47290e7642dd41d94437dd0e2c0f6bfceb0281b5/Include/longintrepr.h#L85) structure.

The raw bits are accessible through the [`ob_digit`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/47290e7642dd41d94437dd0e2c0f6bfceb0281b5/Include/longintrepr.h#L87) field, with the length given by [`ob_size`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/47290e7642dd41d94437dd0e2c0f6bfceb0281b5/Include/object.h#L114). The data type of the digits, and the actual number of boots they hold is given by the `typedef` [`digit`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/47290e7642dd41d94437dd0e2c0f6bfceb0281b5/Include/longintrepr.h#L45) and the macro [`PYLONG_BITS_IN_DIGIT`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/47290e7642dd41d94437dd0e2c0f6bfceb0281b5/Include/longintrepr.h#L44). The latter must be smaller than `8 * sizeof(digit)`, larger than 8, and a multiple of 5 (so 30 or 15, depending on how your build was done).

Luckily for you, there is an "undocumented" method in the C API that will copy the bytes of the number for you: [`_PyLong_AsByteArray`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/47290e7642dd41d94437dd0e2c0f6bfceb0281b5/Include/longobject.h#L163). The comment in [`longobject.h`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/47290e7642dd41d94437dd0e2c0f6bfceb0281b5/Include/longobject.h#L144) reads:

> ```
> /* _PyLong_AsByteArray: Convert the least-significant 8*n bits of long
>    v to a base-256 integer, stored in array bytes.  Normally return 0,
>    return -1 on error.
>    If little_endian is 1/true, store the MSB at bytes[n-1] and the LSB at
>    bytes[0]; else (little_endian is 0/false) store the MSB at bytes[0] and
>    the LSB at bytes[n-1].
>    If is_signed is 0/false, it's an error if v < 0; else (v >= 0) n bytes
>    are filled and there's nothing special about bit 0x80 of the MSB.
>    If is_signed is 1/true, bytes is filled with the 2's-complement
>    representation of v's value.  Bit 0x80 of the MSB is the sign bit.
>    Error returns (-1):
>    + is_signed is 0 and v < 0.  TypeError is set in this case, and bytes
>      isn't altered.
>    + n isn't big enough to hold the full mathematical value of v.  For
>      example, if is_signed is 0 and there are more digits in the v than
>      fit in n; or if is_signed is 1, v < 0, and n is just 1 bit shy of
>      being large enough to hold a sign bit.  OverflowError is set in this
>      case, but bytes holds the least-significant n bytes of the true value.
> */
> ```

You should be able to get a UUID with something like

```
PyLongObject *mylong;
unsigned char myuuid[16];

_PyLong_AsByteArray(mylong, myuuid, sizeof(myuuid), 1, 0);
```